# Getting an error key can't be retrieved gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: apt

Trying to install Java 8 on Ubuntu 14.04

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpkt42czb_/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpkt42czb_/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key EEA14886 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 7B2C3B0889BF5709A105D03AC2518248EEA14886 can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```